# Trying to plot frequency response of a filter Transfer Function in MATLAB, it looks wrong

Tags: filters, transfer-function, frequency-response

I have the transfer function below which is for a IIR filter and trying to plot its frequency response for omega<pi. r=0.99 and theta=pi/3:

[image]

Here is my attempt at implementing it in MATLAB:

```
N=5000;
W=(0:pi/(N-1):pi);
r1=0.99;
theta=pi/3;
z= exp(j*W);

num= (1-r1);
den= (1-2*r1*cos(theta)*z.^(-1)+r1^(2)*z.^(-2));
TF=num./den;
TFdb= 20*log10(TF);
plot(W,TFdb)
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

Apparently it should look like this:

[image]

I am very new to this and can't tell what I'm doing wrong, would appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you derive the second figure? I got the different result using the following code:

```
b = 1 - r1;
a = [1, -2*r1*cos(theta), r1^(2)];
figure; freqz(b, a)
```

[image])

The only problme I can find in your code is that

`TFdb= 20*log10(TF);`

should be

`TFdb= 20*log10(abs(TF));`

Did you take the wrong sign of $a_1$ when calculating second transfer function?

```
b = 1 - r1;
a = [1, 2*r1*cos(theta), r1^(2)];
```

The above code generates the second figure.

Comment: Right the second one must be wrong then, that now gives me a notch filter using abs, what's the reason the response using freqz command looks so different ? The filtered frequency is 1.04 radian but that appears to be different in the freqz plot ? Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Yes ! I did check that now and that's indeed the problem with the second plot, however I'm still confused about the first plot as mention in my above comment.

Comment: @BigRedMachine Note that the x axis in the freqz plot is **normalized frequency**, in my plot it's $0.334 \times \pi$ radian which is equal to 1.047 radian.

Comment: Oh ok, got it now, thanks a lot !